# PHP FATAL ERROR

Tags: plugins, php, wp-admin, phpmyadmin

My website has a PHP Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /var/www/vhosts/katalytes.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/script-loader.php on line 706

[image]

any idea please to fix it because my website is down and i cant work.Also i can't login to wordpress admin

Comment: What version of PHP are you using and what version of WordPress are you running?

Comment: now i have PHP version 8.1.17 and before was 5.4.16

Comment: And what version of WordPress? It sounds like you updated to a PHP version that was not supported by the version of WordPress you are using. Downgrade your PHP, update WordPress, then upgrade PHP again.

Comment: The first version of WordPress to support PHP 8.1 is WordPress 5.9. See the [PHP Compatibility](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/references/php-compatibility-and-wordpress-versions/) page. Also note that just because WP Core supports a given PHP version doesn't mean all plugins and themes will also support it.

Comment: I have the exact same error in my WordPress. I have changed $value{0} to $value[0], but the issue persists. I also tried downgrading PHP, but when I do so I get 500 error.

Comment: I just solved my case by checking the errors on a log and asking ChatGpt to point out the issues. Ends up I had a few problems with multiple files. I am not PHP-skilled, so I'm impressed with the power of AI.

Answer (score 0):

Update WordPress Version or change a bracket { } to [ ].If not check plugin deactivate one by one. Plugin is confilct.

Comment: That's a syntax error in a core WordPress file. I don't think it could be a plugin conflict.